# Magento 2 set category to show all products by default

Tags: magento2, categories

I am working with Magento 2 and I need the categories to show all products in each category by default.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean that you want to show all products within the category on the first page. If so then add the below code to **catalog_category_view.xml**.

```
<action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">all</argument>
</action>
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please mark the answer as correct so that it may help future readers. :)